# HIghcharts doughnut chart without all the slices

Tags: javascript, highcharts, donut-chart

I am doing simple doughnut charts that act more as guages in that they have a single data point in the series that doesn't fill the whole. Currently I am putting a second data point into the series to act as the empty space but this has all the pitfalls of needing to hide tooltips and highlighting. What is the best approach to this? I assumed I would be able to set the chart's total value but I couldn't find it in the docs anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In pie series total value is calculated by summing all points' values.

So, based on your point's value and how big the slice should be, add a second point, make it invisible and set `ignoreHiddenPoint` to false.

```
series: [{
  type: 'pie',
  name: 'Brands',
  colorByPoint: true,
  ignoreHiddenPoint: false,
  data: [
  {
    y: 50,
    visible: false
  },
  50]
}]
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/41xqpnzf/1/

Optionally, you can change the `updateTotals()` behaviour and extend it, so you can set a fixed total value.

```
  Highcharts.seriesTypes.pie.prototype.updateTotals = function() {
var i,
  total = 0,
  points = this.points,
  len = points.length,
  point,
  ignoreHiddenPoint = this.options.ignoreHiddenPoint,
  fixedTotal = this.options.fixedTotal;

if (!Highcharts.isNumber(fixedTotal) || fixedTotal < 0) {
  // Get the total sum
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    point = points[i];
    // Disallow negative values (#1530, #3623, #5322)
    if (point.y < 0) {
      point.y = null;
    }
    total += (ignoreHiddenPoint && !point.visible) ? 0 : point.y;
  }
} else {
    total = fixedTotal;
}

this.total = total;

// Set each point's properties
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  point = points[i];
  point.percentage = (total > 0 && (point.visible || !ignoreHiddenPoint)) ? point.y / total * 100 : 0;
  point.total = total;
}
};
```

And then in the options

```
series: [{
  type: 'pie',
  name: 'Brands',
  fixedTotal: 100,
  colorByPoint: true,
  data: [50]
}]
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/41xqpnzf/2/

Highcharts also has a gauge chart, so maybe this is what you are looking for - no adjusting a pie chart.